# Heat conduction equation with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary condition

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, heat-equation

I want to prove that the approximaton $$\int_0^1u^2(x,t) dx \leq \int_0^1u_0(x)dx$$ holds for $t>0$ where \begin{cases}
u_t-u_{xx}=0,&\text{if $0<x<1, t>0$}\\
u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0, & \text{if $t>0$}\\u(x,0)=u_0(x), &\text{if $x\in(0,1)$} \end{cases}
What I got so far:

From the the fact $$f(t)=\int_a^t f'(s)ds +f(a)$$ we obtain $$\int_0^tu^2(x,t)dx=  \int ...+\int_o^tu_0^2(x)dx $$

Can anyone tell me what to fill in in "...". Then I can show that $... \leq 0$ and I am done.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the equation by $u$ and integrate with respect to $x$ on $[0,1]$:
$$
\int_0^1u_t\,u-\int_0^1u_{xx}\,u=0.
$$
Integrating the second integral by parts and using the boundary conditionswe get
$$
\frac12\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^1u^2+\int_0^1(u_x)^2=0.
$$
Since the second term is non-negative, we see that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^1u^2\le0.
$$
It follows that $\int_0^1u^2$ is decreasing as a function of $t$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. 

Admittedly I didn"t get the steps or don"t understand in which way they are linked to my approach, I am pretty new to differential equations.

Can you please explain it a little more precisely? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is a standard way of obtaining inequalities in PDE's. Multiply the equation by the appropriate factor ($u$, $u_x$, $u_t$ or a combination of them all) and integrate. Transform some of the terms integrating by parts and using the boundary conditions, observe if some of the terms are positive or negative, and obtain an inequality.